# How to increate the performance when using group in LINQ

Tags: c#, performance, linq, model-view-controller

Database

```
Cars       | CarDetails         | Owners
----------------------------------
Id         | CarDetailId        | Id
Name       | CarId              | CarId
Type       | CarId              | OwnerName
           |                    | PhoneNumber
```

LINQ Code

```
var intiQuery = from c in Cars
              join cd in CarDetails
              join o in Owners
              select new { c,cd,o}

var results = from qry in intiQuery 
                           group new { qry.c, qry.cd, qry.o} by qry.c.Id into g
                           select new
              select new { CarId= g.Key,
                           Name = g.Select(g=>g.c.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                           Type = g.Select(g=>g.c.Type).FirstOrDefault(),
                           Price= g.Select(g=>g.cd.Price).FirstOrDefault(),
                           OwnerName= g.Select(g=>g.o.OwnerName).FirstOrDefault(),
                           PhoneNumber= g.Select(g=>g.o.PhoneNumber).FirstOrDefault(),
                         }
```

My question is simply how to increase the performance when calling this query as you can see for each field, I need to.Select().FirstOrDefault() to get the corresponding data. If let's says I got 100 data I will need to get the data one by one 500 times it will take ages to display the data.

Extra Info in case someone not clear.

```
Cars
Id    |Name            |Type
-----------------------------------
1     |Toyota          |Family

CarDetails
CarDetailId | CarId       | Price
-----------------------------------
1           | 1           | 200000

Owners
Id| CarId       | OwnerName   | PhoneNumber
-----------------------------------
1 | 1           | Mitch       | 48774800
2 | 1           | Camilo      | 87404078
```

The result I wanted to get is something like this hope some of you can have a clearer picture

```
CarId| Name   | Type   | Price  |OwnerName        |PhoneNumber 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1    | Toyota | Family | 200000 | Mitch,Camilo    | 48774800,87404078
```

Comment: Why are you using cross-joins instead of simple inner/left joins? That query makes no sense as it's currently written. Actually, I'm not even sure that compiles at all

Comment: @MitchWheat@CamiloTerevinto Please have another read on my question, Had updated Ty.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely **not** the best solution, but it will certainly be easy to understand and if you are not filtering the data then it may be good enough.

As you state, the performance problem is because your hitting your database hundreds of time, and so we can easily avoid that by simply pulling the information from the database in three simple queries.

```
var allCars = Cars.ToList();
var allCarDetails = CarDetails.ToList();
var allOwners= Owners.ToList();
```

Once you have all this information in memory, you can manipulate the in-memory objects to produce the results you need.

```
var results = (from car in allCars
               let owners = allOwners.Where(a => a.CarID == car.Id)

 select new
 {
     CarID = car.Id,
     car.Name,
     car.Type,
     Price = allCarDetails.Where(a => a.CarID == car.Id).Select(a => a.Price).SingleOrDefault(),

     OwnerName = String.Join(',', owners.Select(a => a.Name)),
     PhoneNumber = String.Join(',', owners.Select(a => a.PhoneNumber))
 }
 );
```

If your tables have a lot of extra fields which you have not mentioned, then we may want to change the initial three queries to just pull the information required.